# Completion with for-loop in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, firebase, swift3

I'm trying to code a function with Firebase, which permits to know if a username is taken or not.

```
for username in dict.values {
               if username as? String == self.usernameText.text! {
                  appDelegate.visualReturnBottom(message: "Username already taken.", color: brandBlue, backgroundColor: UIColor.white)
                  return
               }
}
```

The problem is, that I would like to change the View Controller if the username is not taken. For that, I have to wait that the loop is over, and I really don't know how I could do that.

I would like to add this part of code "if the loop is over...:"

```
let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InscriptionSecondVC") as! Inscription2TableViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Just write the two lines "below" the loop?

Comment: addition to @Sweeper ' s answer; write UI change code in main queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're checking a dictionary of values for a username match, you HAVE to wait until the loop is complete. There's no other way to perform that check. As your code is currently constituted, this should work.

```
for username in dict.values {
    if username as? String == self.usernameText.text! {
        appDelegate.visualReturnBottom(message: "Username already taken.", color: brandBlue, backgroundColor: UIColor.white)
            return
       }
}

// if the username is already taken, you will never reach this point.
let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InscriptionSecondVC") as! Inscription2TableViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

As for [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386328/1717855), I agree, and you should think about restructuring your data. This is just an answer to your specific question.

Comment: Cheers @dstepan +1

Comment: Oh ok I was not sure if the lines after the for-loop were called after that the lood is over. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take full advantage of Firebase's features and structure your database a little different to help you do this more efficiently.

You may want to try creating a usernames node and structuring it like so. When a user signs up with a username, you then add their username as the KEY and the VALUE as 1. This then allows you to simple check if the usernames tree contains a specific username:

```
usernames:
- Bob: 1
- Dan: 1
- Billy: 1
```

This then allows you to simply check if usernames tree has the child of the usernameText.text output like so:

```
func handleCheckUsername() {
    guard let username = self.usernameText.text else { return }
    let reference = Database.database().reference()
    reference.child("usernames").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.hasChild(username) {
            print("Username is taken.")
        } else {
            print("Username isn't taken.")
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: It was what I did but I had to change this architecture because %username* couldn't handle point or $ for example ... :/